# malware on website but how does it get there

Tags: javascript, iframe, web, malware, spyware

I have noticed one of my websites has an iframe added into it which links to a malware site or similar (won't include URL, but the domain is `s l u x x q q g y k e w o l m o l i . i n` without the spaces).

It's just html / css and javascript...no Wordpress installed or any form of content management system. I am going through the html files to remove any instances of it but wha ti would like to know is how i protect against this in the future I.E how did someone manage to get it onto my website?

Any help or resources much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Someone probably has got hold of your hosting details I would ask your hosting company to check their ftp logs for any access to your account.

If you are using unsecured ftp your details would be sent over the internet in plain text, always use SFTP or FTPS.